# Neural Network doesn't learn - simple classification problem

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I am currently trying to learn simple neural network recognize 4 different outputs. There are 2-value-inputs which are actually something like this:

output + uniform(-0.2,0.2) + 1

There are only 200 records of that data - but that's important for me to stay with as little data as possible.

Example of input and output next to it:

```
0.9936288071867917,1.0163870658585894  -  0

2.0133450399223953,1.9965272907556022  -  1

3.013918319917813,3.018102735071009  -  2

3.9935640040186025,4.00379069782054  -  3
```

I tried to set different number of epochs, hidden neurons and activation functions. The thing is I want to keep neural network very simple - that means only two hidden layers with max number of about 20 hidden neurons per layer. 
No matter what I do it still doesn't learn or learns very poorly.

Here's code

```py
import keras
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#import pandas as pd
#import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn import metrics

seed = 10
np.random.seed(seed)

dataset = np.loadtxt("dataset.csv",delimiter=',')
#dataset = shuffle(dataset)

X = dataset[:,:2]
Y = dataset[:,2]

#print(X)
#print(Y)

(X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test) = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.10, random_state=seed)
input_shape = (2,)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.core.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.core.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_split=0.10,epochs=30)


val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test)
print('\nCost = ',val_loss,'\nAccuracy = ',val_acc,'\n')
```

I still get results looking like this through epochs(almost the same) and evaluation:

```py
Cost =  1.40975821018219 
Accuracy =  0.20000000298023224
```

What can I do to improve that neural network?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you might want to change is the activation function in your last layer. Since you have 4 different outputs, softmax is the correct activation function.

```
model.add(keras.layers.core.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

The next thing you should do is to replace

```
 model.add(keras.layers.core.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
```

with

```
  model.add(keras.layers.core.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
```

Comment: Okeey I did it. Accuracy raised to about 0.4 after 30 epochs and fell down after. Still nothing satisfying :x Anything more I can do?

Comment: Raised number of samples to 1000 for one output. Everything now works but still -  Its too much data for my research :\ . The other thing is that MATLAB can actually classify it very good with  nnstart  tool using only 50 samples per output. So there must be some way to make that keras nn better am I allright?

Comment: If your accuracy does not increase that much, it means that your neural network is underfitting. That means that you may want to use more layers as well as more neurons per layer, so that the neural network is more suited for your dataset.Try this as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more to it, but the first thing that comes to mind is normalizing your data. as you can see in this plot: [image: this plot]

 the value of sigmoid does not differ greatly for 1, 2,3 and 4. if, however, you're values were between -1 to 1, you would get much better results.